# Typescript nested type mapping

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to handle model validation in typescript.
I'd like to be able to capture the nested types of the validation definition.

For example, I want to be able to create the validator like this.

```
const validateUser = createValidator({
  name: {
    first: {
      value: "First"
    },
    last: {
      value: "Last"
    }
  },
  age: {
    value: 32
  },
  hasOnboarded: {
    value: false
  }
});
```

This would create a validateUser function that takes a model of the specified
type and validates its types.

I'd like to be able to capture the type so that validateUser knows to accept,
objects that conform to the interface.

```
type ValidateUser = typeof validateUser;
```

Should be type

```
(
  model: {
    name: {
      first: string,
      last: string
    },
    age: number,
    hasOnboarded: boolean
  }
) => boolean
```

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, with the use of 2.8's features, conditional types and the `infer` keyword.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20createValidator%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20value%3A%20any%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20%7B%20value%3A%20any%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3E(modelDescriptor%3A%20T)%3A%20(validationSubject%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5Bkey%5D%20extends%20%7B%20value%3A%20infer%20R%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20R%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BinnerKey%20in%20keyof%20T%5Bkey%5D%5D%3A%20T%5Bkey%5D%5BinnerKey%5D%20extends%20%7B%20value%3A%20infer%20R%20%7D%20%3F%20R%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20validateUser%20%3D%20createValidator(%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20first%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%22First%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20last%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20%22Last%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20age%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%2032%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20hasOnboarded%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

```
declare function createValidator<
  T extends {
    [key: string]: { value: any } | { [key: string]: { value: any } }
  }>(modelDescriptor: T): (validationSubject: {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends { value: infer R }
    ? R
    : {
      [innerKey in keyof T[key]]: T[key][innerKey] extends { value: infer R } ? R : never
    }
  }) => boolean;

// const validateUser: (validationSubject: { name: { first: string; last: string; }; age: number; hasOnboarded: boolean; }) => boolean

const validateUser = createValidator({
  name: {
    first: {
      value: "First"
    },
    last: {
      value: "Last"
    }
  },
  age: {
    value: 32
  },
  hasOnboarded: {
    value: false
  }
});
```

Let's break it down, since this is a bit complicated.

First, our function accepts a type parameter `T`, with the constraint that it must be an object, where every key must be either a `{value: any}` or a nested object where every key is such a `{value: any}`.

Our return type is an object, such that for every key in T, we examine the type. If it is of type `{value: <whatever>}`, infer the `<whatever>` (and call it `R`), the type of that key's value is R (a.k.a. whatever type the original had under the `value` key).

If it isn't of type `{value: <whatever>}`, then by our original constraint it must be of type `{[key: string]: {value: <whatever>}}`, so the return type becomes a second level mapping over that inner object, again extracting the type of whatever is in the `value` of the nested object.

If it is neither (which is not possible, thanks to our constraint), the return type for the key will be `never`. That part should never be reached.

Comment: Thanks that works great. It only works 2 levels deep though. Do you think it would be possible to do this recursively, to allow an infinite depth?

Comment: @Cytren That would make TypeScript a turing complete typesystem, which it is not. I'm afraid it's not possible to do recursively.